# Angular 2 bug na url depois do auto compile

Tags: angular, angular-routes, routing, angular2-http

Toda vez que minha aplicação Angular auto compila, a url nunca é reiniciada mas minha aplicação volta pra página inicial do mesmo jeito. Então se eu estou na seguinte URL:

```
http://localhost:4200/alguma-url
```

Ai eu faço alguma mudança no código, o Angular 2 auto compila para aplicar as mudanças e volta para a página inicial, porém com a mesma URL anterior e não a referente a página inicial. Então se eu tento visitar algum link o Angular concatena a URL e deixa ela mais ou menos assim:

```
http://localhost:4200/alguma-url/alguma-url
```

Eu não sei como mas a aplicação continua funcionando, mas é claro em um determinado momento ela para carregar as páginas e então eu tenho que resetar a URL manualmente.

Isso está me tomando muito tempo e eu gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito de definir uma URL do tipo "root" para quando o Angular compilar sozinho.